# "Incomparable types: java.lang.String and int" in Terminal

Tags: java, terminal, while-loop

I was coding a simple Java program for guessing a right answer in school, and when I brought it home, it come across errors.

At first I changed TerminalIO.KeyboardReader to java.util.Scanner, and now when I run it through Terminal, it returns "Incomparable types: java.lang.String and int".

Any help? Really confused.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class guess { 

       public static void main(String [] args) {
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
           Random generator = new Random();
           System.out.println("I am thinking of a number from 1 to 10.");
           System.out.println("You must guess what it is.");
           System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
           int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
           String x = keyboard.nextLine();
           int guessNum = 1;
           while (x != randomNumber) {
                  System.out.println("Guess again!");
                  x = keyboard.nextLine();
                  guessNum ++;
                }
                System.out.println("RIGHT!");
                System.out.println("You got it correct in " +guessNum + " guesses.");

}
```

}

Comment: Because they, well .. are. The error message said as such. Convert one to the same type as the other and *then* compare. (Remember to use `equals()` for comparing Strings.)

Comment: specifically, which errors did you come across?

Comment: @hd1 The one in the title :x

Comment: You are literally comparing a string (x) to an int (randomNumber). What is it about the error message that you don't understand?

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare an int and a String.

You can do this:

```
int someInt = 6;
String someString = "6";
String intAsString = Integer.toString(someInt);

if (someString.equals(intAsString)) {
    System.out.println("Yay");
}
```

---

You can convert a String to a number like this:

```
int someInt = 6;
String someString = "6";
try {
    int stringAsInt = Integer.parseInt(someString);
    if (stringAsInt == someInt) {
        System.out.println("Yay");
    }
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("String is not an integer");
}
```

Comment: Hurrah! Door #3 had the prize. (As a bonus, it's an example of how to approach the problem, better for learning! The other alternative is to convert the string to an integer first .. which might be good for completeness.)

Comment: @jahroy I thought the same thing, but when I use int, it produces another error. Any idea how I can fix my program?

Comment: When you "_use int_" it "_produces another error_"... You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Try running the code above. Does it work for you, or does it produce errors? It worked before and it doesn't anymore, I'm so confused! Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: It's up to you to run the above code and figure out what's wrong.  If you'd like help, the best way to get it would be to describe the error specifically. Of course the above code doesn't work... That's why you asked the question in the first place!  We don't know what changes you've made to it **OR** what error message you're getting (because you haven't told us).

Comment: It has to be a java.util.Scanner error, because when I ran it through BlueJ (school's IDE) and added TerminalIO to it, it ran perfectly.

Any idea on how to get this code (http://goo.gl/STvHp) to translate to java.util.Scanner?

Comment: Nobody uses Scanners in the real world... You'll have to read the Scanner documentation and figure it out:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html  It will be a great learning exercise!

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing a String with an int (which are incompatibletypes)

convert your int to a string and compare it

```
       while (!(x.equals(Integer.toString(randomNumber)))) {
```